# Implicit cast fails for myClass<T> when T is IEnumerable<U>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I know and I think I understand about the [(co/conta)variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) issue with IEnumerables. However I thought the following code would not be affected by it.

```
[DataContract]
public class WcfResult<T>
{
    public WcfResult(T result)
    {
        Result = result;
    }

    public WcfResult(Exception error)
    {
        Error = error;
    }

    public static implicit operator WcfResult<T>(T rhs)
    {
        return new WcfResult<T>(rhs);
    }

    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Exception Error { get; set; }
}
```

This class is to mimic BackgroundWorker's [RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbd7wse7) so I can return errors from my WCF service without faulting the connection.

Most of my code is working fine so I can do things like this

```
public WcfResult<Client> AddOrUpdateClient(Client client)
{
    try
    {
        //AddOrUpdateClient returns "Client"
        return client.AddOrUpdateClient(LdapHelper);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new WcfResult<Client>(e);
    }
}
```

and it works fine, however the folowing code gives a error

```
public WcfResult<IEnumerable<Client>> GetClients(ClientSearcher clientSearcher)
{
    try
    {
        //GetClients returns "IEnumerable<Client>"
        return Client.GetClients(clientSearcher, LdapHelper, 100);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new WcfResult<IEnumerable<Client>>(e);
    }
}
```

Where the error is

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myNs.Client>'
to 'myNs.WcfResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myNs.Client>>'. An explicit
conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What is going wrong that is causing this error to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, you've been foiled by a less-than-obvious restriction of the C# Language Specification.

> For a given source type S and target type T, if S or T are nullable
>   types, let S<sub>0</sub> and T<sub>0</sub> refer to their underlying types, otherwise S<sub>0</sub> and
>   T<sub>0</sub> are equal to S and T respectively. A class or struct is permitted
>   to declare a conversion from a source type S to a target type T only
>   if all of the following are true:
>
> · S<sub>0</sub> and T<sub>0</sub> are different types.
>
> · Either S<sub>0</sub> or T<sub>0</sub> is the class or struct type in which the
>   operator declaration takes place.
>
> · **Neither S<sub>0</sub> nor T<sub>0</sub> is an interface-type.**
>
> · Excluding user-defined conversions, a conversion does not
>   exist from S to T or from T to S.

Now, it doesn't seem like this would apply because your implicit conversion function takes a generic parameter, but this restriction seems to apply to types used as generic arguments just as much. I took your example and changed `IEnumerable` to `List` (a full type, not just an interface) and it compiled without error.

To make a long story short, you're simply going to need to wrap any expression that returns an interface type in the `WcfResult` constructor, because the implicit cast won't be available for it.

```
return new WcfResult<IEnumerable<Client>>(Client.GetClients(clientSearcher, LdapHelper, 100));
```

Comment: WTF...that's why I can't reproduce OP's issue on my machine, I'm using `Foo<List<A>>` for testing!